# Where can you rent an RV like a car in the USA?

Tags: usa, rental, one-way, motor-homes

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm interested in any nationwide (USA) companies which allow you to rent an RV in one place, and turn it in at another place. I know you can do this with cars, but I've never heard of doing it with an RV. If so, what companies are there that provide this service?

Note that I'm not asking this because I don't know who to use, but rather because I was unable to find anybody that provided this service. However, my search terms probably weren't that great either.

This is the style of RV I have in mind:

[image: RV Example]

Comment: I swear we've had this before, but I can't find it for the life of me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was sure we've had this before, but it must not have been for the US.  Short answer - yes, such services exist.

For example, [Cruise America does one way RV rentals](http://www.cruiseamerica.com/rent/one-way-rv-rentals/).

There's also an article on budgettravel.com about this:

[One-way RV rentals are booming, and here's a secret for savings](http://www.budgettravel.com/blog/one-way-rv-rentals-are-booming-and-heres-a-secret-for-savings,10625/)

They include several companies in the article, which would surely serve you well.